# PrimeFaces 4: Manage select node and contextMenu on same treeNode

Tags: primefaces, contextmenu, jsf-2.2

help me please !!!
On my page I have two parts:

- a part "menu" where I use treeNode as choice.
- a second part "central" where I display a page each time a node is selected.

Just that everything runs smoothly. 
The problems began when I associated treeNode with the contextMenu. At each time I right click on a node to view my contextMenu, it shows the loading time of my central page. Looks like right click and select a neoud are confused and whoever takes over is the selection of node.
 Is it possible to separate these two events? 
Is it possible to do otherwise, or have a workaround? 
The workaround I found is to put a commandLink under each node. it did not work, especially for the son nodes.
 Thx for your help

```
<h:form id="formMenuAdmin" >
    <p:panel header="Domaines" id="panelDomaines" style="border: none;width: auto" >
        <p:contextMenu for="treeMenuAdmin" id="contextMenuTreeNodeDomaine" nodeType="Domaine">
            <p:menuitem id="menuitemAdd" value="Créer " icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#{domaineCtrl.afficherDialogOrg('dialogCreateDgdsVar')}">
            </p:menuitem>                                
            <p:menuitem id="menuitemEdit" value="Editer" icon="ui-icon-search">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem id="menuitemUpdate" value="Modifier" icon="ui-icon-search">
            </p:menuitem>

            <p:menuitem id="menuitemDelete" value="Supprimer" icon="ui-icon-search">
            </p:menuitem>                            
        </p:contextMenu>                            
        <p:contextMenu for="treeMenuAdmin" id="contextMenuTreeNodeSousDomaine" nodeType="Dss">
            <p:menuitem id="menuitemAddDss" value="Créer" 
                                        icon="ui-icon-search" 
                                        actionListener="#{domaineCtrl.afficherDialogOrg('dialogCreateDss')}">
            </p:menuitem>

            <p:menuitem id="menuitemEditDss" value="Editer"
                                        icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem id="menuitemUpdateDss" value="Modifier "
                                        icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#">
            </p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem id="menuitemDeleteDss" value="Supprimer"
                                        icon="ui-icon-search" actionListener="#">
            </p:menuitem>

        </p:contextMenu>
        <p:tree id="treeMenuAdmin" value="#{treeNodeCtrl.rootTreeNode}" 
                                var="doc" selectionMode="single" 
                                selection="#{treeNodeCtrl.selectedTreeNode}" 
                                style="width: auto;border: none" cache="true" >


            <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treeNodeCtrl.onNodeSelect()}"  />

            <p:treeNode id="treeNodeDomaine" type="Domaine"
                                        expandedIcon="ui-icon-folder-open" 
                                        collapsedIcon="ui-icon-folder-collapsed"> 
                <h:outputText value="#{doc.nom}" id="outputTextDomaine#{doc}"/>                                    
            </p:treeNode>

            <p:treeNode id="treeNodeDss" type="Dss"  >
                <h:outputText value="#{doc.nom}" id="outputTextDss"  />                                                 
            </p:treeNode>                                

        </p:tree>
    </p:panel>

</h:form>
```

Comment: Can you show us the contextMenu for the "central" part?

Comment: @rion18, I do not have any contextMenu on central page. I think I poorly explained the problem:
the central page just displays the contents of a selected node (node selected on page menu).

Comment: Ok, I understood. When you right click a node to invoke the contextMenu, then this node is selected, this is the default PrimeFaces behavior. However, on PF 5.0 (from PF 4.0.2) `SelectTreeNodeEvent` was upgraded and included an `isContextMenu()` method. You can see that [here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6243).

Is switching to PF 5.0 an option?

Comment: Yes I can. So, the solution is to simply switch to PF5.0 ? Without changing anything in my code, if I understand you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to PF 5.0 will allow you to use the `isContextMenu` method. The only difference that this will entail is the following, on your `onNodeSelect` method.

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event){
  if (!event.isContextMenu()){
    //original code here.
  }
}
```

This way your original selection code will be executed if a contextMenu is NOT invoked.

Comment: nice. didn't know there was this method here. :D thanks!